# applying compound function on parts of list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have list

```
 t1={{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {3, 10}, {4, 17}, {5, 28}, {6, 41}, {7, 58}}
```

and want to substitute the second part with the biggest prime factor in it, giving

```
{{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {3, 5}, {4, 17}, {5, 7}, {6, 41}, {7, 29}}
```

I can do it by either

```
a = #[[1]] & /@ t1
b = Max /@ FactorInteger[#[[2]] & /@ t1 ]
Transpose[{a,b}]
```

or by

```
MapAt[Max, MapAt[FactorInteger, t1, {All, 2}], {All, 2}]
```

There must be more elegant ways to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
MapAt[First @* Last @* FactorInteger, t1, {All, -1}]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {3, 5}, {4, 17}, {5, 7}, {6, 41}, {7, 29}}
> ```

```
MapAt[FactorInteger /* Last /* First, t1, {All, -1}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {3, 5}, {4, 17}, {5, 7}, {6, 41}, {7, 29}}
> ```

Also

```
Transpose[{#, Map[First @* Last @* FactorInteger] @ #2}] & @@ Transpose[t1]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {3, 5}, {4, 17}, {5, 7}, {6, 41}, {7, 29}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Another option might be

```
 max[y_] := Max[FactorInteger[y][[All, 1]]];
 Cases[t1, {x_, y_} :> {x, max[y]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The same thing can be done using `/.`

```
 t1 /. {x_, y_} :> {x, max[y]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another might be

```
 {#[[1]], max[#[[2]]]} & /@ t1
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In Mathematica, the rule of thumb is that there are at least 10 different ways to do the same thing. Which one is best can depend on what style you prefer and performance of each method.

Comment: Be careful, `Max[FactorInteger[8]]` will give 3 - the power not the factor. You need to replace `Max[FactorInteger[y]]` with `Max[FactorInteger[y][[All,1]]]`

Comment: @flinty yes sure. I was just using OP code for this part. I did not even look at FactorInteger result. Will correct now. Thanks.